# Safari not correctly displaying website, css, html

Tags: html, css, safari

Here is an example from Chrome on android how the website should look like : https://i.stack.imgur.com/RzUSp.jpg

and here is an example from Safari on Ipad Mini 2: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PAj2i.jpg

Safari version doesn't show the proper font for the title and what is most important it doesn't show those links that should be on the left side.

So here is HTML bit of that code that displays those links on the left like 1.0.0.46 or whatever.

```
echo '<div class="patch_table">';
echo '<a class="patchlink" href="'.$patch.'">
    <div class="patch_big">'.$patch.'</div>
    </a>'; 
echo '<div class="patch_small">';
```

And here is css describing those classes

```
.patchlink{
  color: white;
  font-size: 80%;
  width: 28px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: rgba(102, 153, 255, 0.7);
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  margin-bottom: 4px;
}
.patchlink:hover{
    background-color: rgb(102, 153, 255);
}
.patch_small{
    display: flex;
    flex: 1;
    flex-direction: column;
    -webkit-flex: 1;
    -webkit-flex-direction: column;
}
.patch_big{
  position: absolute;
  width: 15px;
  height: 50px;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -8px;
  margin-top: 7px;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  transform: rotate(-90deg) translate(-100%, 0);
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg) translate(-100%, 0);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
}
.patch_table{
    margin-top: 5px;
    display: flex;
    flex: 1;
}
```

and here is also a link to that website: http://89.68.17.183/LeagueNotes/Graves

Comment: What, if you try this? <div class="patchlink"><div class="patch_big"><a href="$patch">$patch</a></div></div>

Comment: You are in quirks mode. All modern web pages are required to have a doctype and you don't have one. Add this as your very first line: <!DOCTYPE html> . Then tell us what happens.

Comment: dev.null that disrupts the css layout completely @Rob I've added Doctype and nothing has changed

Answer (score 0):

I foud the solution too:

1. install the extension of "autoprefix css" 
   https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mrmlnc.vscode-autoprefixer (VS 
   Code)
   https://github.com/sindresorhus/sublime-autoprefixer (Sublime Text)
2. it's automatically renders the css properties to all browsers. in case not done, simply open the css file and select all (ctrl + a) and ctrl + shft + p and type autoprefix css. that's it!
3. check your css files.